# Capybara can't find elements on dropdown lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to troubleshoot a feature spec I'm writing to learn Rails & testing.  It's an edit_spec for a Rails 4 app. I'm using RSpec and Capybara.

The Problem:
Capybara can not find elements from two drop down lists on a form.  Here's the relevant parts of my form's source code:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="appointment_member_id">Member</label><br>
<select id="appointment_member_id" name="appointment[member_id]">
<option value="1">Callis Callis</option>
<option value="2">Rachale Rachale</option>
<option value="3">Hal Hal</option>
<option value="4">Kallis Kallis</option>
<option value="5">Earle Earle</option>
<option value="6">Rudy Rudy</option></select>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="appointment_trainer_id">Trainer</label><br>
<select id="appointment_trainer_id"
name="appointment[trainer_id]"> <option value="1">Jacob Jacob</option>
<option value="2">Michele Michele</option>
<option value="3">Alex Alex</option>
<option value="4">Yanni Yanni</option>
<option value="5">Upton Upton</option>
<option value="6">Willham Willham</option></select>
</div>
```

In my edit_spec, I tried using "option value" and "select id" to get Capybara to select names from the drop-down lists:

```
select('4', :from => 'appointment_member_id')
select('2', :from => 'appointment_trainer_id')
```

The result is a Capybara::ElementNotFound error.  Here's the full text of the error message:

updates an appointment successfully with corrected information (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

```
1) Editing appointments updates an appointment successfully with corrected information
 Failure/Error: select('4', :from => 'appointment_member_id')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find option "4"
```

I researched the issue and documentation for Capybara, and also a Stackoverflow post with similar problem. The poster solved the issue, but couldn't recall how he did it.  I'm baffled as to why Capybara can't find the member and trainer from the drop down list?  The option values and names appear to be visible on the form.  What am I missing? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Capybara simulates user behaviour. So instead of ids and values try to use what the user see:

```
select 'Kallis Kallis', from: 'Member'
select 'Michele Michele', from: 'Trainer'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; unfortunately, it did not solve the problem. I get the same Capybara Element Not Found error as before.  Any more ideas?

Comment: try 'save_and_open_page' method. It saves the page. Then you can look what is the real source of the page.

Comment: Tried save_and_open_page - Capybara is using my options hash to put values on the page, but the member & trainer fields are being populated from the FactoryGirl object. I know this because the names are being generated by the Faker gem. Nothing I do seems to cause Capybara to choose a member or trainer from the drop down list. I'm wondering if this problem could be test environment related. How are drop down lists populated in the test environment?  Other thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the page isn't valid HTML and capybara can't find the element.

Comment: The form was created automatically by the Rails scaffold generator. There's no Javascript or other non-HTML code. Capybara finds the field labels okay, but can not find the values, which are select lists based on collections (i.e. members & trainer names in a drop down menu). Interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the code below, or possibly assign the div and id and replace `"div.field"` with whatever id you choose

```
within "div.field" do
  find("option[value='4']", text: 'Yanni Yanni').select_option
  click_button 'your_submit_button'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the code at my earliest opportunity.

Comment: No problem!  Let me know how it goes -- I had the exact same problem, it seems like select box options can be pretty finicky.  If this solution doesn't work then I can provide you with another possible solution.

Comment: The code generated the following error:  Failure/Error: within "div.field" do
     Capybara::Ambiguous:
       Ambiguous match, found 5 elements matching css "div.field" Perhaps a bit of progress.  Capybara appears to be looking, but is confused.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Good!  That is definitely progress.  Try assigning one of the div's an ID and referencing it that way juuuust to eliminate the ambiguous reference error and see if were making the right kind of progress

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie ...how do I "assign one of the div's an ID" to test this. Sounds like basic HTML/CSS, but can't remember how to do it.

Comment: `<div class="field" id="first_field">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69480/discussion-between-codeinspired-and-kevin-behan).